# Doxygen exclude templates specialized with excluded namespace/type

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

I'm currently working on a C++ library using Boost and I ended up with specialized class templates using a Boost type.

```
template<>
struct BasicFormat<boost::property_tree::ptree, tags::Input_tag>
{ ... };
```

I also have to specialize a Boost template which is not supposed to be displayed in the documentation but I get a Boost namespace reference. I would like to use the exclude symbols property to hide that reference and it works when set like that.

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = ... boost
```

Unfortunately, this also disables the documentation for all classes using `boost::property_tree::ptree` as above. I can see the class in the corresponding namespace but I cannot access its documentation.

Is there a way to hide any namespace/type references without hiding a template specialized with that same namespace/type?

**Edit:**
I know I can achieve the correct behavior with the `@cond` comment, but is it possible to make it a more automated way like the exclude property?